# Programa para diferenciar unidade,dezena,centena e milhar, da erro quando digitado menos de 4 digitos

Tags: python

Estou tentando escrever um programa no Python 3.2 que leia o numero inteiro digitado entre 0 e 9999, e que me de como resposta os respectivos:

- unidade
- dezena
- centena
- milhar

**usando strings ao invés de formulas matemáticas**. Usando formulas matemáticas já obtive o resultado, porem em strings sempre recebo o erro "string index out of range", ao digitar menos de 4 dígitos ( menos de milhar)
meu código abaixo

```
entrada= str(input("Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: "))
entrada.split() # fiz com que os numeros digitados sejam separados e listas individuais de 0 a 3

#lista = [0,1,2,3]

unidade = entrada[3]
dezena = entrada[2]
centena = entrada[1]
milhar = entrada[0]


print(""" 
Unidade = {}
Dezena = {}
Centena = {}
Milhar = {}

""".format(unidade,dezena,centena,milhar))
```

Ele roda sem erros se digitar números na casa do milhar, porem qualquer coisa abaixo disso já mostra o mesmo erro na 6 linha `unidade = entrada[3]`
Qual seria a possível solução pra isso?

Comment: Isso `entrada= str(input("Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: "))` não precisa converter resultado de input em string pois a função input já retorna uma string. Tenta com `entrada= f'{input("Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: "):>4}'` veja a documentação [Minilinguagem de especificação de formato](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) e veja o exemplo https://ideone.com/kVpLqm

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método `string.rjust` para adicionar o dígito 0 a esquerda do seu número sempre garantindo que ele tenha um tamanho de quatro caracteres.

```py
>>> '1234'.rjust(4, '0')
'1234'
>>> '123'.rjust(4, '0')
'0123'
>>> '1'.rjust(4, '0')
'0001'
```

---

Como comentado, coisas no seu código não fazem sentido ou são desnecessárias:

1. A função `input` **sempre** retorna uma string, portanto não precisará converter para string novamente;

```py
entrada= input("Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: ")
```

2. A linha `entrada.split()` simplesmente é inútil no seu código, pois ela divide a sua string nos espaços em branco, retornando uma lista. Porém, sua string não possui espaços em branco, o que retornaria algo como `['1234']` e mesmo assim não faz sentido, pois o retorno do `split` não está sendo atribuído à nenhuma variável, portanto é completamente ignorado no Python;
3. Você não precisa quebrar a string em uma lista para acessar as posições, o tipo string no Python já te permite isso:

```py
>>> '123'[0]
'1'
>>> '123'[1]
'2'
>>> '123'[-1]
'3'
```

---

Um código, Python 3.10, que resolve o problema sem as considerações acima seria:

```py
while not 0 <= int(entrada := input("Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: ")) < 10000:
    print('Número inválido, tente novamente!')
else:
    entrada = entrada.rjust(4, '0')

milhar, centena, dezena, unidade = entrada

print(f'{unidade=}, {dezena=}, {centena=}, {milhar=}')
```

Executando ficaria:

```
Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: 10000
Número inválido, tente novamente!

Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: -10
Número inválido, tente novamente!

Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: 42
unidade='2', dezena='4', centena='0', milhar='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá!
Isto está acontecendo porque o programa pressupõe que a entrada tenha 4 dígitos para que se possa acessar o 3° índice, isto é, o quarto valor da string, em:

```
unidade = entrada[3]
```

Podemos resolver isto da seguinte forma:
#Caso o 3° índice (4 valor) da entrada não exista; coloque um zero no 1° índice, para que a complete as 4 casas.
if entrada < 1000:
entrada = str(entrada)
entrada = "0"+entrada

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
entrada= int(input("Digite um numero de 0 a 9999: "))

if entrada < 1000:
    entrada = str(entrada)
    entrada = "0"+entrada

entrada.split()

unidade = entrada[3]
dezena = entrada[2]
centena = entrada[1]
milhar = entrada[0]

print(""" 
Unidade = {}
Dezena = {}
Centena = {}
Milhar = {}
""".format(unidade,dezena,centena,milhar))
```

Assim poderíamos adicionar infinitas casas, colocando sempre zeros à frente...

Porém, a maneira da resposta acima está muito melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa desenvolver mais este código, nele está implícito que o valor do input sempre será uma lista com tamanho 4, em caso de o usuário digitar "1000" irá funcionar corretamente, porem se ele digitar 100 não será, e quando você tentar buscar o valor na quarta posição da lista ile erá dar erro.
O camarada ali em cima já deu a dica de ouro, colocar zeros na frente do número caso **len** for menor que 4. Você pode usar um if para checar o tamanho da string inicial, e em seguida adicionar a quantidade necessária.

Comment: Pedro Miceli, legais as suas observações, mas acontece que o Stack Overflow não é um Fórum. Nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas práticas e objetivas sobre linguagens de programação. Essa publicação faz bem o diagnóstico porém não resolve o problema. Você consideraria [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/565303/edit) seu post e apresentar uma solução concreta?